# Gmail font color issue

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a problem with the font color of the second email sent to a gmail address. I have the following syntax:

```
<p style="color:white">Dear Sir/Madam</p>
```

But in the next email, it adds a new span around the text forbidding me to control the style:

```
<p style="color:white"><span class="im">Dear Sir/Madam</span></p>
```

The problem is similar to the following question:
[Font Color in HTML Email - Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923263/font-color-in-html-email-gmail)

However, in my case it is adding a span instead of just adding a class and therefore forbidding from adjusting the color. I tried using a different color (#FFFFFE) as well as !important but didn't solve the issue. As far as I know, CSS3 won't assist me as well since most things are not allowed in gmail.

How can I avoid having this span in my emails?

**Edit:**
Attached an image that shows the color was overridden through !important but still appears purple.
[image: Color was overridden]

Comment: Even if it adds span,color style should be applied. Or you can try .removeClass(); to remove class of span. http://jsfiddle.net/oockoqyz/1/

Comment: The question is for HTML emails. Most email clients do not support JS and therefore I cannot use it. Email clients also render HTML differently and so it ignores some of the known rules (That is why i am using inline). Attached is an image shows that the color was truly overridden but still appears purple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using inline styles, other styles are not accepted if more simply

Comment: Yes, I know that. And I am using inline styles everywhere. The span with class "im" is not added by me, it is added by gmail. So I can't put inline style there.

Comment: try so in .im {color: #ff00 !important;}

Comment: Perfect, thanks Alex. I thought gmail does not support classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391262/does-gmail-support-css-classes